# Организация структуры и наследования моделей в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Есть проект библиотеки на `Laravel 5.2`. Есть стандартная модель `App\User`. В ней сейчас находятся все методы для отношений и выглядит эта модель следующим образом:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
    }

    /**
     * Comments written by user
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }

    /**
     * Books read by user
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function books()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Book::class)->loadRating()->withPivot('finished');
    }

    /**
     * All books, that user is waiting for
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function expectations()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Book::class, 'user_book_line');
    }

    /**
     * Confirmations, that was sent to users when it's their turn to take a book
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function confirmations()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Book::class, 'books_confirmations');
    }
}
```

Все методы, которые связаны с взаимодействием пользователя и книг, на данный момент, я вынес в отдельный трейт, но считаю это неправильным. Я хочу, чтобы вся логика, связанная с книгами у пользователя была в отдельной модели, например, находилась в директории `app/Library/User.php`.
Дальнейшее расширение проекта (добавление новых фич и т.д.) будут приводить к захламлению всем функционалом модель `User`, а этого мне необходимо избежать.

В обычном наследовании базового класса `User` есть проблема - вызов `Auth::user()` будет возвращать именно базовый класс `User`.
Подскажите, как будет правильней организовать структуру наследования в данном случае?

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте наследуемые классы и метод в User

```
public function getSomeClass() {
    return SomeClass::find($this->id);
}
```

либо чтобы можно было использовать eagerLoading

```
public function getSomeClass() {
    return $this->hasOne('SomeClass');
}
```

либо можно расширить класс Auth, прописать его в aliases, и добавить там методы вызова сразу нужного класса `Auth::someRole()`, подробнее [тут](https://laravel.ru/posts/20).

Answer (score 0):

Можете в `config/auth.php` в `providers.users.model` указать любой класс и он будет использоваться системой для аутентификации.

В laravel многое можно настроить через конфиги а что останется настраивается через сервис провайдеры :)

Comment: Мне необходимо, чтобы в конфиг файле я мог указать несколько классов. Допустим, я хочу, чтобы был не только класс `App\Library\User`, но и `App\Mail\User`, который будет содержать методы для работы пользователя с почтой. Таким образом я смогу это реализовать?